# Random Number Generator with Beta Distribution

Tags: c++, c, random

I need the c or c++ source code of a function like `betarand(a,b)` that produces random number with beta distribution . I know that I can use *boost* library but I'm going to port it for CUDA architecture so I need the code. Can somebody help me?
Meantime I have `betapdf`(Beta Probability density function). But I don't know how to use it for creating random numbers :).

Comment: hmm, I guess by definition if numbers are produced in some manner that they can be characterized as part of a distribution, they must not be random. :)  but anyway.. does [this beta function](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/browser/trunk/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c) work for you?

Comment: @Mike, which definition? Do you imply that the linear distribution is "more random" than any other distribution?

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Generating_beta-distributed_random_variates you can generate a Beta distribution from 2 Gamma Distributions.  Since C++11 provides a gamma distribution, it should be possible to use them to create a beta distribution.

Comment: @DaveS Just what I'm doing right now...

Comment: @Mike : rk_beta ? so what's the rk_state parameter :D?

Comment: @sftrabbit~> For me ?! :D I'm eagerly waiting for it!

Comment: @saeed Indeed - for you.

Comment: @sftrabbit ~> 1 year later ! :)

Comment: @saeed Just so you get a notification about - I've updated the class in my answer so it fully conforms to the random number distribution requirements.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The C++11 random number library doesn't provide a beta distribution. However, a beta distribution can be modelled in terms of two gamma distributions, which the library *does* provide. I've implemented a [`beta_distribution`](https://gist.github.com/sftrabbit/5068941) in terms of `std::gamma_distribution` for you. As far as I can tell, it fully conforms with the requirements for a Random Number Distribution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

namespace sftrabbit {

  template <typename RealType = double>
  class beta_distribution
  {
    public:
      typedef RealType result_type;

      class param_type
      {
        public:
          typedef beta_distribution distribution_type;

          explicit param_type(RealType a = 2.0, RealType b = 2.0)
            : a_param(a), b_param(b) { }

          RealType a() const { return a_param; }
          RealType b() const { return b_param; }

          bool operator==(const param_type& other) const
          {
            return (a_param == other.a_param &&
                    b_param == other.b_param);
          }

          bool operator!=(const param_type& other) const
          {
            return !(*this == other);
          }

        private:
          RealType a_param, b_param;
      };

      explicit beta_distribution(RealType a = 2.0, RealType b = 2.0)
        : a_gamma(a), b_gamma(b) { }
      explicit beta_distribution(const param_type& param)
        : a_gamma(param.a()), b_gamma(param.b()) { }

      void reset() { }

      param_type param() const
      {
        return param_type(a(), b());
      }

      void param(const param_type& param)
      {
        a_gamma = gamma_dist_type(param.a());
        b_gamma = gamma_dist_type(param.b());
      }

      template <typename URNG>
      result_type operator()(URNG& engine)
      {
        return generate(engine, a_gamma, b_gamma);
      }

      template <typename URNG>
      result_type operator()(URNG& engine, const param_type& param)
      {
        gamma_dist_type a_param_gamma(param.a()),
                        b_param_gamma(param.b());
        return generate(engine, a_param_gamma, b_param_gamma); 
      }

      result_type min() const { return 0.0; }
      result_type max() const { return 1.0; }

      result_type a() const { return a_gamma.alpha(); }
      result_type b() const { return b_gamma.alpha(); }

      bool operator==(const beta_distribution<result_type>& other) const
      {
        return (param() == other.param() &&
                a_gamma == other.a_gamma &&
                b_gamma == other.b_gamma);
      }

      bool operator!=(const beta_distribution<result_type>& other) const
      {
        return !(*this == other);
      }

    private:
      typedef std::gamma_distribution<result_type> gamma_dist_type;

      gamma_dist_type a_gamma, b_gamma;

      template <typename URNG>
      result_type generate(URNG& engine,
        gamma_dist_type& x_gamma,
        gamma_dist_type& y_gamma)
      {
        result_type x = x_gamma(engine);
        return x / (x + y_gamma(engine));
      }
  };

  template <typename CharT, typename RealType>
  std::basic_ostream<CharT>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT>& os,
    const beta_distribution<RealType>& beta)
  {
    os << "~Beta(" << beta.a() << "," << beta.b() << ")";
    return os;
  }

  template <typename CharT, typename RealType>
  std::basic_istream<CharT>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<CharT>& is,
    beta_distribution<RealType>& beta)
  {
    std::string str;
    RealType a, b;
    if (std::getline(is, str, '(') && str == "~Beta" &&
        is >> a && is.get() == ',' && is >> b && is.get() == ')') {
      beta = beta_distribution<RealType>(a, b);
    } else {
      is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return is;
  }

}
```

Use it like so:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
sftrabbit::beta_distribution<> beta(2, 2);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  std::cout << beta(gen) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Hope you still read this after a couple of years, but if I'm not mistaken reading this generation prescription: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Generating_beta-distributed_random_variates

the generate function should return x_gamma(engine) / 
(x_gamma(engine) + y_gamma(engine), and not use the same x value twice.

Comment: @Daniel I have been inactive on Stack Overflow for a few years now and I'm finally looking over any comments on my posts. Now I'm a bit worried in case anyone's used this implementation and it being possibly incorrect - however, I tried implementing it instead as you've described and it does not appear to generate the appropriate distribution. As it is in this answer, however, the distribution appears to be correct. Unfortunately, I cannot find a good source that shows whether the X gamma distribution is sampled once or twice. If you have any more info, please let me know!

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the code. As per a quick check, the suggestion by @Daniel to go with `x_gamma(engine) / (x_gamma(engine) + y_gamma(engine)`, i.e., use two different samples of `x`, easily produces very large values ( >> 1), because `x + y` in the denominator can be much smaller than the other `x` sample in the numerator. This does not fit the beta distribution property of being bound by 1. When the same `x` sample is used in both numerator and denominator, the resulting value does not exceed 1. The original code by @Joseph Mansfield has more chances to be the right one then!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the code that `gsl` uses for producing random numbers with the beta distribution. They use a little weird way of produging them, as you have to pass a random number generator to the function, but surely you can get what you need.

Here's the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Beta-Distribution.html) and the [web page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)

Answer (score 1):

Boost "inverse incomplete Beta" is another fast (and simple) way to simulate Betas.

```
#include <random>
#include <boost/math/special_functions/beta.hpp>
template<typename URNG>
double beta_sample(URNG& engine, double a, double b)
{
  static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0,1);
  double p = unif(engine);
  return boost::math::ibeta_inv(a, b, p); 
  // Use Boost policies if it's not fast enough
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the random number generator implementations in `NumPy`: [NumPy distributions source](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/browser/trunk/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c)

They are implemented in C, and work very fast.